# Approach to get values of a dynamically generated textView

Tags: android, textview

I successfully created a dynamic TextView and a Button now when ever the button was clicked the value of a TextView changes.
But the problem is I have a final "submit button" outside a loop which should get the INDIVIDUAL values of each TextView and I cant think of a way how to do it can someone pls give me an approach for this thanks!. pls be nice..

code

```
Cursor citem= sdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ITEM INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON item.categoryid = category.id where category.categoryname='"+fcat+"'", null);  
 ScrollView scrollView= new ScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout mainLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
Button border = new Button(this);
border.setId(Integer.parseInt(cuser.getString(cuser.getColumnIndex("id"))));;
    border.setText("ORDER");
    while (citem.moveToNext())
    {
        byte[] blob =citem.getBlob(citem.getColumnIndex("itemimage"));
        int id = Integer.parseInt(citem.getString(citem.getColumnIndex("id")));

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearLayout.setTag(id);
            int i;

            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setId(id);
            iv.setImageBitmap(dh.getPhoto(blob));

            final TextView txtquantity = new TextView(this);
            txtquantity.setId(id);
            txtquantity.setText("0");
            txtquantity.setTextSize(20);

            final TextView txtprice = new TextView(this);
            txtprice.setId(id);
            txtprice.setText(citem.getString(citem.getColumnIndex("itemprice")));
            txtprice.setTextSize(30);

            ImageButton btn1 = new ImageButton(this);
            btn1.setId(id);
            final int id_ = btn1.getId();
            btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int i = 0;

                    i=Integer.parseInt((String) txtquantity.getText())+1;
                    txtquantity.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    totalprice.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(totalprice.getText().toString())+(Integer.parseInt(txtprice.getText().toString())*1)));
                }
            });                
            ImageButton btn2 = new ImageButton(this);
            btn2.setId(id);
            final int id2_ = btn2.getId();
            btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {        
                    if(Integer.parseInt((String)txtquantity.getText())<=0)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          int i=0; 
                          i= Integer.parseInt((String) txtquantity.getText())-1;
                            txtquantity.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                         totalprice.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(totalprice.getText().toString())-(Integer.parseInt(txtprice.getText().toString())*1)));
                    }
                }
            });   
          linearLayout.addView(iv);
          linearLayout.addView(txtprice);
          linearLayout.addView(btn1);
          linearLayout.addView(txtquantity);
          linearLayout.addView(btn2);
          mainLayout.addView(linearLayout);



    }
     mainLayout.addView(totalprice);
     mainLayout.addView(border);
     scrollView.addView(mainLayout);
     setContentView(scrollView);
```

Comment: its too long but if you really want it

Comment: If you remove all of the dead/commented out code it would be shorter

Comment: @benpearson done tnx for the review!

Comment: Is it not possible to just keep a a list of TextViews you've created and send that list off for processing, to get the values?

Comment: @nameSpace can you shoe me an example for that?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what problem you're having?  If it's just reading all the TextViews you created in the loop, then you should just keep a list, and send it off for processing when you submit...

```
List<TextView> tv_list = new ArrayList<TextView>();

while(...){

 //In loop..add your tv's
 TextView some_tv = new TextView()
 tv_list.add(some_tv);

 ...

}


//In the submit, send them off for processing...
private void process_tvs(List<TextView> tv_list){

    for(TextView tv:tv_list){
        //Assuming your tv's have numbers...
        int val = Integer.valueOf(tv.getText().toString());
        //do something....
    }

}
```

Comment: I have some question here for example. my textview-value is incremented everytime the button is clicked how can i UPDATE the list instead of INSERTING another value for the list

Comment: Your buttons appear to update the texview text value.  The textviews in the list are references to the same textview (they aren't clones, but the same textView), so they will have the updated value as well.

Comment: @nNameSpace what do you mean by this?. even though i dont put an button onCLickEvent that will update the list it will still update the list?